# How to remove the Telegram Indicator applet

Tags: indicator, telegram

Am scratching my head about whether there's a way to have my Telegram Desktop not display a blue "You've got mail" icon in the lower right corner...I believe this is called the "indicator applet."

I need some of them, so I don't want to turn off that section entirely, which seems doable.  It seems like there should be a simple way to turn off Notifications or something like that...yet thus far, I'm unable to find it either within Telegram or within the Indicator Applet sections.

It has been a long week though so perhaps this is staring me in the face.  If anyone knows how to do this, would love your help!

I'm using Lubuntu 16.06LTS, with Telegram version 1.2.6.  In the Settings > Notifications list I get only 4 options:

--Desktop Notifications (unchecked)
--Play Sound (unchecked)
--Include Muted Chats in Unread Count (checked)
--Use Native Notifications

I'm afraid I don't recall if I installed this using apt-get or did it by .deb or .gz.

Here's an image:  [Telegram tray icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhC2m.png)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Some questions, what is your Ubuntu version and flavour? How did you install Telegram? Which icon exactly are you trying to remove? (Could you post a screenshot?) There is usually a "*show tray icon*" option in Telegram Desktop, is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: So sorry, yes, I just edited the original post to include that info.  Hope it's helpful!  (And no, exactly like you said, I'm mystified to NOT find any "show tray icon" tickbox...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, the answer is that the "show tray icon" isn't in the notifications section but further down in the General settings.  I have it after all.  Posting this as a reminder to all that looking carefully in the Settings may just be the answer one needs.  Thank you @pomsky for letting me know what to look for!  That helped.

Comment: if you solved your issue and your own answer satisfies you please mark it down as solved.